# Any way to get phone statusbar (battery, wifi, notifications) showing on Harry Potter: Wizards Unite?

Tags: settings, 9.0-pie

Question is pretty self-explanatory, I got a Nokia 8 with Android 9 (not rooted), started playing HP: Wizards Unite and am very irritated that the upper status bar of the phone which shows battery, notifications, clock, wifi etc is no longer visible unless I swipe on it, but then it again dissapears. I tried searching from the phone settings as well as the games settings, but to no avail. I'm looking for a way to get the upper phone status bar to be permanently visible while playing the game, so I can monitor my battery life easily.

Ps. if this is not the right forum for this question, feel free to vote on migrating it to the right one, just thought some android guru might be able to help.

If anyone has a solution to this, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Sounds like the app is running in full-screen mode. If there is not settings in the HP app to disable this ask the developers to add such a feature.

Comment: hmm yes it could be that it is by default (and not yet possible to change) on full-screen mode. Funny thing is, that the same developer has made Pokemon Go, which shows the statusbar by default on the same phone in question. As HP has been built on Pokemon, I don't know why it doesn't show the status bar. Could be a feature not yet implemented in the game, but if there is a workaround that someone knows, I'd love to hear it.